# Multi-stage Docker; Reinstalling packages(?)

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying my hands at my first multi-stage docker deployment after using docker for a few months now and am trying to follow a guide ([link](https://snyk.io/blog/10-best-practices-to-containerize-nodejs-web-applications-with-docker/)) as the foundational instruction but I have some questions about the second step of the build. At some point during final stage of the build I get the non-fatal prompt to run "npm install -g npm@9.8.0";

Dockerfile

```
# ===== [ Build Image ] ==================================================================== #
# Use the latest version of Node.js as the build image.
FROM node:latest AS build

# Update OS and install dumb-init; dumb-init is a simple process supervisor and init system 
# designed to run as PID 1. It is used to handle being the  parent of child processes and
# ensures signal forwarding and child reaping, which are needed to avoid zombie processes 
# and handle proper termination.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dumb-init

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy required files for the container.
# File Descriptions:
#     package.json: NodeJS packet manager manifest file; i.e. metadata about the project.
#     package-lock.json: Version tracking document supporting package.json.
COPY package.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app/

# Update npm within the Docker container
RUN npm install -g npm@9.8.0

# Install all the dependencies as defined in the package.json
RUN npm ci --only=production

# ===== [ Production Image ] =============================================================== #
# Use the latest version of node:alpine as the base image.
FROM node:alpine

# Set static environment variables
RUN export NODE_ENV=production

# Copy dumb-init application from build container.
COPY --from=build /usr/bin/dumb-init /usr/bin/dumb-init

# Force user swap to node if not already.
USER node

# Set the working directory inside the container.s
WORKDIR /usr/src/mongo_setup

# Copy NodeJS dependency files.
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules /usr/src/mongo_setup/node_modules

# Copy required files for the container.
# File Descriptions:
#     index.js: Core app that reads mongo_config.js and makes required changes.
#     mongo_config.js: Basedline configuration document setup_mongo aligns DB with.
COPY --chown=node:node package.json package-lock.json index.js mongo_config.js /usr/src/mongo_setup

# Set the command to start the application. This command will be the default one that Docker 
# will execute if no other has been specified when starting the container
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Since I didn't copy the npm file this is expected but is this an issue? Should I be moving the npm update to the prod system and is this the best way of doing this?